# Understanding wait() and notify() methods

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to understand how Java's `wait` and `notify` methods work. As per the documentation, `wait()` causes thread to wait for subsequent calls to `notify()` or `notifyAll()` methods but for some reason `notify` doesn't interrupt "waiting":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("thread1 is started, waiting for notify()");

            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }

            System.out.println("waiting is over");
        }
    });

    thread1.start();

    // unblock thread1 in 2 seconds

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    synchronized (thread1) {
        thread1.notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to call `wait()` and `notify()` on the same object. You are not doing that in your code - you implicitly call `wait()` on the `Runnable` object, and `notify()` on the `Thread` object.

Comment: `wait()` and `notify()` are low-level methods that are meant to be used in a very specific way to implement higher-level synchronization classes.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html  You are likely to run in to trouble if you use them any differently.  Also, in most cases, you can use the higher-level synchronization classes that are provided by the `java.util.concurrent` package, and avoid the risks associated with crafting your own.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840397/concept-behind-putting-wait-notify-methods-in-object-class/17841450#17841450

Comment: @jameslarge yep, i'm already familiar with high-level Java stuff related to concurrency and multithreading, just wanted to understand how all of that works at the lowest level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `notify` the object that is being `wait`ed on, not the thread that is waiting.

In your case the object `wait`ed on is an instance of an anonymous inner class, which is problematic because you cannot easily obtain a reference to it in order to `notify` it. You could solve this by extending `Thread` directly:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("thread1 is started, waiting for notify()");

        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("waiting is over");
    }
};
```

Now the `this` (in `synchronized (this)`) refers to the thread itself, and the `wait` is called on the thread object too. In this case your current call to `notify` should be fine, since it notifies the same object (which *happens* in this case to be the thread that is waiting - but just to be clear, that need not be the case).

It isn't considered good practice to use an object for synchronisation that may also be used elsewhere; instances of Thread would be an example of this, and in fact the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) specifically advises against it:

> It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

Also, you should correctly handle *spurious wakeup*; that is, `wait` may return because `notify`/`notifyAll` was called elsewhere or perhaps was not even called at all. As the documentation [also says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)):

> A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied. In other words, waits should always occur in loops [...]

Therefore, your example should really use a separate variable to track whether the wakeup was intentional (due to an explicit `notify`) or not.

Comment: yeah, that was the case - I totally missed the fact that `this` is referencing anonymous `Runnable` class and not the `thread1` variable. Thank you!

Comment: Using `thread.wait()` and `thread.notify()` usually is not recommended because the `Thread` class itself uses `wait()` and `notify()` on `Thread` objects.

Answer (score 1):

> for some reason notify doesn't interrupt "waiting":

@davmac's answer is correct but for posterity, there are some other ways you can do it because extending `Thread` and calling `wait()` and `notify()` on the `Thread` object is not recommended.

The best way would be to create a lock object.  Making your lock objects `final` is always a good pattern although here it is also necessary to use it in the inner class.

```
final Object lock = new Object();
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    ...
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // always a good pattern
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
      ...
}
...
synchronized (lock) {
    lock.notify();
}
// might as well wait for it to finish
thread1.join();
```