# Why Object class has methods wait() and notify() and Class class does not have?

Tags: java

Someone asked me this question in an interview. I am not sure if it is a valid question or not. If it is please reply. Thanks

Comment: Can there be a situation where you want to "wait" on a specific instance of an object? Think about it... ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concept behind putting wait(),notify() methods in Object class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840397/concept-behind-putting-wait-notify-methods-in-object-class)

Comment: I just wonder which interview you were asked this question.

Answer (score 6):

`java.lang.Class` implictly extends `java.lang.Object`, like every other object type, so it inherits both this methods from `Object`:

```
Class<?> clazz = new Object().getClass();
clazz.wait();
```