Understanding the behavior of wait() in Java threads?
I am learning about threads in Java and trying to understand what thread.wait() does.
Here is a piece of code I wrote:
class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
      System.out.println("Inside thread");
    });

      thread.wait();

  }
}


which gave
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:366)
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:339)
    at Scratch.main(scratch_125.java:8)

then I checked over the internet and found out that I needed to lock over the thread to call wait() and to lock something we need to use synchronized.
This time, I didn't get IllegalMonitorStateException but the code kept running and never printed "Main thread working fine?". However, I was expecting it to give IllegalStateException because I am directly putting it in a waiting state before running the thread using thread.start().
class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
      System.out.println("Inside thread");
    });


    synchronized (thread) {
      thread.wait();             // keeps waiting here
    }

    System.out.println("Main thread working fine?"); // never reached here

  }
}


When I added some debugging breakpoints I realized that the code keeps waiting at thread.wait(). This confused me, as per my understanding main thread should not wait for other threads if thread.join() is not written in the code.
After some research, I found out that the thread.wait() releases the lock from the thread. but still can't understand why the 'main' thread stops executing.
Why is this code behaving like this?
Also, If I add thread.start() then thread.wait() has no effect and the code doesn't wait at thread.wait().
class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
      System.out.println("Inside thread");

      try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    });


    thread.start();

    synchronized (thread) {
      thread.wait();
    }

    System.out.println("Main thread working fine?");

  }
}


Why did not code wait this time?

wait() is not a method defined on Thread but on Object. I recommend to read the corresponding documentation at docs.oracle.com, and maybe an accompanying tutorial like this one over at baeldung.com


IllegalMonitorState: as the doc states: "The current thread must own this object's monitor lock."; 2) thread.wait() does not necessarily wait for the thread to run/finish - here thread is the instance/object used as lock (it may even not be a Thread, neither be started); 3) "code keeps waiting" - sure, until some code calls thread.notify() (or .notifyAll()) or interrupts the actual Thread; 4) "code doesn't wait at thread.wait()" it actually does wait, but the Thread class uses itself as monitor (it calls something like this.notifyAll() or similar) so it is awaking the wait


IMO, If you want to understand what wait does, you should work through the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

The method for waiting for the completion of a thread is join() If you call wait() on an object, whether a thread or something else, you should ask yourself, what this code is waiting for. If you can’t tell what is supposed to stop the waiting, then you shouldn’t be surprised when the wait never stops.

I read all the comments, At first I didn't understand anything, but then I read the article provided by @Turing85, and after some more reading, I could understand @user85421 answer. But still, I could not understand why wait() gets executed before the thread isn't started. As per the cycle of a Thread, the thread needs to be in a RUNNING state to call wait() over it which changes it to a NON-RUNNABLE state.

You’re still confusing yourself by thinking calling wait() on a thread instance means anything. You can call wait on any object. The fact that the object is a thread in your case, is irrelevant. You can write Object o = new Object(); synchronized(o) { o.wait(); } and of course, this will wait forever. The result is the same as calling wait() on a Thread object representing a never-started thread. And, of course, the thread calling wait() on an object is the one going from RUNNING to WAITING.

Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840397/concept-behind-putting-wait-notify-methods-in-object-class/17841450#17841450

It is an extremely bad idea (as in, never do it, there are no exceptions to this rule that I am aware of) to lock on a thread (synchronized  (someInstanceOfThread). That's because the Thread API itself does this.
Wait is part of the low-level notification system
wait is part of a set: It goes together with its opposite, which is notify - and that comes in 2 flavours (notifyAll and notify).
wait is not 'sleep'.
Thread.sleep(1000L) is simply:

Wait until 1000L have passed. If that happens, exit normally.
-OR- some other thread invokes t.interrupt() where t is a ref to this thread's Thread object... then, stop waiting, and exit via InterruptedException.

wait is the same (it also accepts a duration), but it adds a third bullet:

-OR- some other thread invokes x.notify()/x.notifyAll(), where x is a reference to the same object we invoked wait on.

However, wait has additional requirements. For starters, you invoke it on an object - it's an instance method every object has, vs. sleep which is a static method. The thing you invoke it on is important - it's what other threads need to invoke notify on for wait to be useful.
Also, in order to use this system (any of the 3 - wait, notify, or notifyAll) you must be inside a synchronized (z) {} block, where the z expression evaluates to the same object you are calling .wait() (or .notify()) on. If you aren't, you get IllegalMonitorException as you observed.
Additionally, x.wait() (which therefore means you are in synchronized (x), or it'd immediately throw IllegalMonitorEx) will release the lock on x, and therefore, wait() returning via its intended mechanism (some other thread calls notify()) does not actually immediately continue. After all, by definition, the other thread that notified itself is inside synchronized(x) or it couldn't have called notify() (as they'd get an immediate IllegalMonitorEx). Thus, wait() waits for the notify and for the notifying thread to exit the synchronized block. Then the waiting thread re-obtains the lock on x and only then does code continue.
It works that way because it's a framework of sorts.
A note about locks
Just about every example out there tells you that fields should be private and if you want to expose that field directly, you'd instead write a getter and perhaps a setter method.
The underlying idea behind that common trope is that anything your API exposes is thus outside of your control and will forever be unless you make a breaking change. In other words, if you expose a field, then you lost control of it: Any other code (outside of your direct control) can change it, therefore, you as an API designer must forever more keep that in mind when modifying your class. With setters, you have options. You could virtualize the field (say, you have a field int age;, but a later update means you need to change things a bit and it's a lot simpler if you just have a LocalDate birthDate. If your class had public int age; you're forced to release a breaking update. If you had setters, no problem! setAge() can simply do this.birthDate = LocalDate.now().minusYears(age), and getAge() can do return (int) ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(birthDate, LocalDate.now()).
The exact same principle applies to locks! They should almost never be public!
and this, is generally 'public' - code that isn't directly in this package is likely to be capable of obtaining references to it. Locking on an instance of thread is even worse - that's spaghetti global state: Anybody anywhere can get a ref to all threads, and thus, your locks. Hence, do not do this. It's even worse than that - lots of code locks on things and if 2 unrelated pieces of code both use the same object for their internal locking implementation details, hoo boy. Everything just goes to heck in a handbasket - it'll be hard to test (as JVMs have a heck of a lot of 'may or may not' in the spec in regards to threads, so some behaviour on one JVM may not be observable on yours, or some JVM may behave differently on an ARM chip than on an INTEL one), but definitely problematic.
Hence, you always make private locks unless you really, really know what you are doing. And in that rare case of having a public lock, your javadoc MUST explain at length precisely what that's about, or it's necessarily bad code.
This gets us to a simple example:

class CentralStationBoard {
  private final List<String> arrivals = new ArrayList<>();
  private final Object lock = new Object();

  public void trainArrives(String trainName) {
    synchronized (lock) {
      arrivals.add(trainName);
      lock.notifyAll();
    }
  }

  public void enableBoard() {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
      while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        synchronized (lock) {
          while (!arrivals.isEmpty()) {
            String trainName = arrivals.remove(0);
            System.out.println("Train has arrived: " + trainName);
          }
          try {
            lock.wait();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Board turned off");
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    });
    t.start();
  }
}

The above code tries to implement a train station. Each train's safety/location system is a thread, and the central big board showing arriving trains is also a thread. Anytime a train arrives, its on-board systems send a message to the arrivals board announcing their arrival.
But how do we coordinate this? After all, 2 trains might arrive simultaneously, for example.
The above code shows how. All interaction with the queue of arrivals messages (the List<String>) goes via synchronized so no 2 train systems can fall over each other trying to simultaneously announce, and the board's processing of these messages is similarly protected.
But, to avoid the CPU of the central arrivals board going crazy, you can't just keep looping the inner body (that starts with while (!arrivals.isEmpty())) - because then as long as no trains are coming, the board is just repeatedly acquiring the lock, doing nothing, releasing it, over and over again. Your CPU would get very hot, the batteries run out very quickly. We want to wait for a train to arrive.
But we can't use Thread.sleep() either - if we, say, sleep for 500 milliseconds or so, and a train arrives a millisecond after we do that, then the board waits another 499 millis, for no reason at all, before seeing the message. No good either.
Thus, wait/notify.
But.. actually, don't.
The above works, but you should really have implemented that with something like java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue - the sychronized system is a very low level concept that is somewhat hard to use; the juc package uses it (and often faster alternatives, even) to provide much, much nicer APIs. Such as BlockingQueue which could have done this job better.
NB: Note that InterruptedException cannot possibly occur unless you yourself write t.interrupt() somewhere. The spec is clear on this - other than t.interrupt() that exception cannot occur (for example, if the user quits your app, or hits CTRL+C on the command line, or whatnot, threads are not interrupted. Instead, the JVM runs shutdown hooks and then just exits on the spot. And, java.* code never calls interrupt. So, what do you do when InterruptedException occurs? You tell me - why did you write t.interrupt() - what were you trying to accomplish there? Do that in the catch block. If you didn't write that (and you probably shouldn't), it really doesn't matter. My advice? throw new RuntimeException("interrupted", e).
